# How to use PHP Function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

How can use a PHP Function into a Javascript function, i tried this.

```
<script>
    $("#swipe-product").touchwipe({
    wipeLeft: function() {
        <?php echo "<img src='img/" . $l_qurries->GetNextProduct($g_ProductId, $g_Winkel) . ".jpg' id='artikel' alt='shopping-bag'/>"; ?>
    },
    wipeRight: function() { 
        <?php echo "<img src='img/" . $l_qurries->GetPrevProduct($g_ProductId, $g_Winkel) . ".jpg' id='artikel' alt='shopping-bag'/>"; ?>
    },
    min_move_x: 20,
    min_move_y: 20,
    preventDefaultEvents: true
    });
</script>
```

but the image that i want to change don't change by a slide on my mobile (the slide function is working very well without the php function, tested with alert's)

i'm new with javascript and dont know much about it.

Comment: You can't. Your question shows you didn't understand what PHP is really. PHP is processed server-side, and it disappears completely from the generated page that is sent to the client (the browser).

Comment: Try to learn ajax http://bit.ly/1CMMiDq

Comment: Ajax is the solution !

Comment: I think OP is trying to mix PHP and javascript, thinking PHP can execute client-side, just like JS does.

Comment: I know that php is server side, only i dont know how javascript are exactly works because im never used that manualy.

Comment: The PHP in the script will only run 1x when the page is first rendered.  It is then dynamically writing that value into the JavaScript.  You can view source on your page to see what the PHP put into the JavaScript.

Comment: @paul Zepernick if im checking in the sources, it gives the url that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with a form that send a javascript variable to a php variable and i used the php variable into a php function.

```
<form name="swiping" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="" />
</form>

<script>
    $("#swipe-product").touchwipe({

    wipeLeft: function() {
    var j_ProductId = <?= $g_ProductId ?>;

    if (j_ProductId < <?= $l_LastProduct ?>){
        j_ProductId++;
        document.swiping.productid.value = j_ProductId;
        document.swiping.submit();
    }

    },
    wipeRight: function() { 
    var j_ProductId = <?= $g_ProductId ?>;

    if (j_ProductId > <?= $l_FirstProduct ?>){

        j_ProductId--;
        document.swiping.productid.value = j_ProductId;
        document.swiping.submit();
    }

    },
    min_move_x: 20,
    min_move_y: 20,
    preventDefaultEvents: true
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do. JavaScript is being executed in the browser, while PHP is being executed on the server side.

Your JavaScript can invoke a PHP script using Ajax to load products, result of that script can then be dynamically injected into DOM as suggested by comments, this will however introduce latency. You could show a loading icon while user is waiting for the next product to load.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If your list is not excessively long you can generate the markup with PHP and then manipulate with JavaScript.

You can combine these 2 approaches to improve user experience and load a batch into the DOM and then when user goes close to the end of the list load with Ajax another batch.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running the script in a file with a `.php` extension, it should result something like the following:

```
<script>
    $("#swipe-product").touchwipe({
    wipeLeft: function() {
        <img src='img/example-image-1.jpg' id='artikel' alt='shopping-bag'/>
    },
    wipeRight: function() { 
        <img src='img/example-image-2.jpg' id='artikel' alt='shopping-bag'/>
    },
    min_move_x: 20,
    min_move_y: 20,
    preventDefaultEvents: true
    });
</script>
```

The PHP will output `<img>` tags in the middle of your `<script></script>` block. Those strings should be wrapped in `"` or `'` marks. Without those, you're going to receive a Javascript error message, which you can view in your Web Inspector Console.

You need to do something with those `<img>` tags that are being generated. For example, you could do the following:

```
<script>
    $("#swipe-product").touchwipe({
    wipeLeft: function() {
        // Append the <img> tag to the body tag
        $('body').append("<img src='img/example-image-1.jpg' id='artikel' alt='shopping-bag'/>");
    },
    wipeRight: function() { 
        // OR append the <img> to a <div> tag with an ID
        $('#img-goes-here').append("<img src='img/example-image-2.jpg' id='artikel' alt='shopping-bag'/>");
    },
    min_move_x: 20,
    min_move_y: 20,
    preventDefaultEvents: true
    });
</script>

<div id="img-goes-here"></div>
```

I'm not familiar with the `.touchwipe()` method that you're using, but you can read up on how jQuery's [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) works, or find something similar.

**This is based on the assumption that you are using PHP within a `.php` file on a server that supports PHP.**